# Loading variables from a separate file for Rake

Tags: ruby, rake

I am trying to get into Ruby / Rake. I thought it would be a good idea to separate some configuration out of the Rakefile in a file called configuration. This file has the following content:

```
email="nobody@nowhere.com"
password="somepassword"
proxy_server="someproxy.com:8080"
puts "config loaded"
```

Then in my Rakefile I load the configuration file by

```
load 'configuration'
```

and use the variables defined later on, e.g.:

```
task :dummy do
    sh = "echo #{proxy_server}" 
end
```

But then I get an error stating that the variable is not defined:

```
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `proxy_server' for #<Object:0xb783595c>
```

How can I access the configuration variables defined in the configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility: variables from configuration file are not visible in the script that has executed it. You need to establish a common context, for example using global variables (even if globals are evil:-)) like:

```
$proxy_server="someproxy.com:8080"
```

and then

```
task :dummy do
    sh = "echo #{$proxy_server}" 
end
```

But since rake files are Ruby themselves why use a separate configuration file in the first place? If you need to change the config you can as well edit rake file.